# allow logins from multiple domains in phpbb?

Tags: php, subdomain, forum, dns, phpbb

I've read a bunch of different things, none of which seem to be my situation.  I have a site which uses a phpbb forum, and we also have multiple wordpress blogs which can use the database of phpbb via a plugin named wp-phpbb (can't post another hyperlink, but its at simplicitypoint dot com) .  It works great for something that is on the same domain, like http://www.domaina.com/blog can access a blog at /forum on the same domain .  Recently ( we are building a blog community) a new blog joined us that had his own domain name.  I can get the plugin to install, and see the forum ucp.php and config.php as they are in teh same virtual directory, but phpbb will not redirect the login back to the server.  If anyone can help me I would be SO grateful.

I have a basic understanding of programming and am very good with computers (I Work in IT) so hopefully I can help any follow up questions you may have.  I also have a completely seperate testing area to try things out in first.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can only do those things across one domain. The problem is probably the cookie for remembering the login is trying to be send across two domains, which the browser won't allow (following the cookie RFC). If that's not the problem, I would try a different wordpress plugin like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/phpbbauth/

Comment: hmmm, i'll try that... i guess that would just work in a different way, but I may have the same problem..i'll let you know